# Python in QGIS to convert from dxf to shapfile

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, convert, dxf

Within the QGIS python console, I'm trying to convert a dxf file into a shp file. I run this section of code, and am not getting an error but no output file is generated. Wondering if I'm missing something in here.

```
import sys
from osgeo import ogr
import re
from os import path

#http://www.agt.bme.hu/gis/gdal/dxf2shp.py
# for QGIS script runner
def run_script(iface):
    dxf_name = "C:/Users/dxf_file.dxf"
    target_name = "C:/Users/shape_file.shp"
    # enter geometry type ogr.wkbPoint | ogr.wkbLineString | ogr.wkbPolygon
    shp_type = ogr.wkbLineString
    # enter regexp to filter layers
    dxf_layer_filter = '.*'
    res = convert(dxf_name, target_name, shp_type, dxf_layer_filter)
    if res == 0:
        (shpdir, shpfile) = path.split(target_name)# load the shape
        iface.addVectorLayer(target_name, shpfile, 'ogr')
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. No function is called at all.
Use the complete code from
http://www.agt.bme.hu/gis/gdal/dxf2shp.py
.


You can also use the Plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/

Comment: Yes, that code does nothing because you never call the `run_script` function.